# unable to render data from ngrx store to component

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am using ngrx and angular.
I have a component which has a dropdown in module 'A'. On change of dropdown i set the selected value in my ngrx store.

Now I have a grid component in module 'B'. My task is to fill grid with a dataset(which is being filtered  on basis of saved dropdown ID).

I am able to get the dataset in my sandbox. This sandox is nothing but a layer b/w component and store

```
public getAllDevices(): Observable<Array<Device>> {
    return this.appStateManager.getFromStore(state => state.serviceProviderState.devices);
  }


devices$ =this.appStateManager.getFromStore<ServiceProvider>(state => 
    state.serviceProviderState.selectedServiceProvider)
    .subscribe(data=>{
    this.deviceService.getAllDevices(data.id)
    .subscribe((devices: Array<Device>) => {
      console.log(devices);
      this.appStateManager.saveToStore(new SetAllDevices(devices));
    });
    });
```

In the above code i am fetching data from appStateManager which is nothing but a wrapper over store api. Then after getting selectedId, i called getAllDevices which gives me a filtered dataset. I can see my desired dataset in console.log.

Now i need to show this devices$ in my grid. For which i have written code as below:

```
      @Component({
         selector: 'device-list',
         template: '<data-grid [devices]="devices"></data-grid>',
          })

     export class DeviceListContainer implements OnInit {
  devices: Device[];  
  devices$= this.monitoring.devices$;     
  constructor(private monitoring: MonitoringSandbox) {       
    this.monitoring.getAllDevices().subscribe((data)=>{          
       this.devices=data;
       console.log(this.devices);
     })       
  }
```

MY grid isn't getting filled. Where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

devices$ in your DeviceListContainer is a Subscription, you already subscribed to it in your sandox it's not an Observable< Array < Device> >. Also you subscribing again inside the devices$ you need to use rxjs operators to format you request. for the construction try using it like so

```
 let deviceSubscribtion = this.monitoring.getAllDevices().take(1).subscribe(data=> {
         this.devices=data;
         console.log(this.devices);
  });
```

Dont forget to unsubscribe from the deviceSubscribtion when you destroy component or you will end up with memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your code, your doing subscribe inside another subscribe.
Angular use rxjs and it can help you a lot. you should compose that subscriptions with some operators.

for example

```
someObserble$.pipe(
  mergeMap(someObserbleResulat => {
   // return some Obserble
  }),
  switchMap(someObserbleResulat => {
   // return some Obserble
  })
)
```

when you compose SwitchMap you are completing the previous observable.
when you compose MergeMap you not completing the previous observable

with the use of switchMap, we can clean your code to ==>

```
this.appStateManager.getFromStore<ServiceProvider>
.pipe(
    switchMap(state => state.serviceProviderState.selectedServiceProvider),
    switchMap(data => this.deviceService.getAllDevices(data.id)),
   ) 
  .subscribe((devices: Array<Device>) => {
     console.log(devices);
     this.appStateManager.saveToStore(new SetAllDevices(devices));
  });
```

you can see how this code turns into cleaner, readable and maintainable.

you should use angular

```
aync
```

pipe that automatically subscribes to your observable and unsubscribes when the ngOnDestory invokes.

```
@Component({
       selector: 'device-list',
       template: '<data-grid [devices]="devices$ | async"></data-grid>',
})
export class DeviceListContainer implements OnInit {
   devices$: Obserble<Device[]>;  

   constructor(private monitoring: MonitoringSandbox) {       
     this.devices$ = this.monitoring.getAllDevices() 
}
```

if you want to add a console to see what has returned in this subscribe you can add 
the tap operator

```
.pipe (
   tap( res => { console.log(res)})
)
```

some useful reading:

https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0
https://www.nerdeez.com/articles/rxjs/top-operators

enjoy